# XSLT - How delete a repeating and empty element?

Tags: xslt, xpath

I have the following piece code of **XML**:

```
<para>
  <break/>
  <break/>
  <break/>
  <break/> Text1<break/>
  <break/> Text2<break/>
  <break/>
  <break/>
  <break/>
  <break/>
</para>
```

I need to get following:

```
 <para>
      <br>
      Text1
      <br>
      Text2
      <br>
  </para>
```

I wrote **XSLT** it:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
        <html><body><xsl:apply-templates /></body></html>
  </xsl:template>
         <xsl:template match="para">
            <p><xsl:apply-templates /></p>
        </xsl:template>
        <xsl:template match="break">
            <xsl:if test="following-sibling::break and .='' ">
                <br><xsl:apply-templates /></br>
            </xsl:if>
        </xsl:template>
```

But it doesn't work. Can you help me?

Comment: Are you sure your xml file is like this ?! and You are sure of the output you need ? Because everything seems weird

Comment: This is not the entire XML, and only piece. Yes, I'm sure.

Comment: You are not forgetting some '/', sure ?

Comment: What does it weird for you?

Comment: Sorry, but I didn't write a full xslt, only piece where I have trouble. I can write full, if it needs.

Comment: Your output is only composed by " <br> <br> ... " and your template has " <br> and </br>". That is one reason

Comment: ok, I wrote a full xslt in my qyestion. See before.

Comment: Your test only selects breaks that are followed by another break AND are empty. I don't know what you wanted to achieve (your desired result isn't even well-formed) but your text will never be printed out. Not least of all because your test is a direct child of the `<para>` tag.

Comment: I added template for <para> in my qyestion. Also I have a template for root, it is a very simple and contains only apply-templates. I didn't add this in question... See before. The only trouble is the template for "break".

Comment: Okay, I can see the problem now. You can't use `following-sibling::break` because that simply returns the next `break` element and skips everything in between, but you can't use `following-sibling::node()` either because you've got a text node between `<break/>`s.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't catch. Could you explain more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found resolving for my trouble:

```
     <xsl:template match="para">
       <p>
       <xsl:apply-templates/>
       </p>
     </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="break">
       <xsl:if test="normalize-space(following-sibling::node()[1]) != '' or name(following-sibling::node()[2]) != 'break'">
          <br/>
       </xsl:if>
    </xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 2):

The output you request is not valid (the `<br>` elements are not closed). Assuming you want to get something like:

```
<p>
   <br/> Text1<br/> Text2<br/>
</p>
```

try:

```
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

...

<xsl:template match="para">
    <p>
        <br/>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="text()" />
    </p>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="para/text()">
    <xsl:copy/>
    <br/>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Wouldn't this also copy the nodes containing ignorable whitespace?

Comment: @biziclop It won't, if you use `<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>` at the top of your stylesheet.

Comment: It works for only sample in question, but if I have a bit other structure with these elements it doesn't work. So I found the resolving. Tnanks your help:)